# Как ajax передать данные, подставить в url и вернуть результат назад?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть index.php
в нем следующий код:

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
    <legend>Test From</legend>
    <label for="name">Название:</label><input id="name" name="" value="" type="text">
    <input value="Send" type="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function call() {
          var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'res.php',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                $('.results').html(data);
              },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
                    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
    <br><br>

    <div id="results" class="results">вывод</div>
```

Файл res.php который принимает переменную $_POST с данными

```
<?php
$array = array();

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://shikimori.org/api/animes/search?q=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User Agent");
if ($content = curl_exec($ch)) {
$array = json_decode($content, true);
}
curl_close($ch);

print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Как передать $_POST в строку curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'shikimori.org/api/animes/search?q=');
после ../search?q=!!СЮДА!! и вывести полученный массив в index.php в div id="results"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /*index.php*/

    <form id="formx">
        <legend>Test From</legend>
        <label for="name">Название:</label>
        <input id="name" name="data" value="" type="text">
        <input value="Send" type="submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $('form#formx').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var msg   = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'res.php',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                //в data должен быть ответ сервера в формате JSON
                var response = JSON.parse(data); //массив в котором ваши данные
                $('#results').html(response[i].{key}); // i - номер объекта, {key} - ваш ключ из массива
              },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
                    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
                }
            });
      });
    </script>


    <div id="results">вывод</div>


    /*res.php*/
    ...
    $url = 'http://shikimori.org/api/animes/search?q='.$_POST['data'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    ...
    print($content);
```

P.S. Ответ основан на предположении, что ваш урл отдает данные в формате `JSON`

Comment: да ответ идет json

Comment: Notice:  Undefined index: data in  $url = 'http://shikimori.org/api/animes/search?q='.$_POST['data'];

Comment: там если я не ошибаюсь он передает данные форматом name=что ввели, нужно без name

Comment: вы ошибаетесь, введенное значение передается через атрибут value, name же указывает имя ключа массива POST

Comment: $_POST['data'] консоль выдает ошибку на 'data' Undefined index

Comment: да я уже понял свою ошибку, теперь загвоздка в выводе результата, блок с id просто скрывается и ничего не выводит

Comment: обновил ответ. И проверьте что jquery у вас подключен

Comment: Unexpected token {"name"}); // {key} - ваш ключ из массива
на первый {

Comment: где то закрывающая скобка ); пропущена в скрипте, и сразу очень сильно извеняюсь за тупые вопросы

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
На ; в конце скрипта

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
на строку  $('form#formx').on('submit', function(e) {

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

Comment: Перекинул его в хедер страницы появилась ошибка
XHR failed loading: POST "http://anime-plus.local/res.php".

Comment: отладил на локальном сервере, исправил ошибки в ответе

Comment: да теперь работает, теперь вопрос, как обойти ограничение в номер обьекта? и вывести все результаты коих 8шт

Comment: циклом for http://javascript.ru/for